# Integration of library embedTLS with LwIP 2.1.0 error on undefined reference to '_gettimeofday'

Tags: arm, cortex-m, lwip, mbedtls

I've tried integrating library mbedTLS with LwIP 2.1.0. I've added the following to my lwipopts.h file

```
#ifndef LWIP_ALTCP
#define LWIP_ALTCP 1
#endif

#ifndef LWIP_ALTCP_TLS
#define LWIP_ALTCP_TLS 1
#endif
```

I've added the library to my project like this and referenced them for the compiler:

[image]

I've also made changes in the mbedtls/include/config.h file such that no windows or linux is used.

I'm getting a "undefined reference to "_gettimeofday" where I've narrowed it down to the only place where this is defined is in my arm-gnu toolchain:

```
#ifdef _COMPILING_NEWLIB
int _EXFUN(_gettimeofday, (struct timeval *__p, void *__tz));
#endif
```

What might the case be? Everything compiles file when I turn LWIP_ALTCP_TLS off but then TLS can't be used. Are there more flags I need to switch on/off?

Answer (score 1):

RTFM: The `_gettimeofday()` function is a system call that the user has to implement when using date and time functions from newlib.

Minimum implementation is rather simple:

```
int _gettimeofday (struct timeval *tp, void *tzp){
  tp->tv_sec = unixTimeInSecs;
  tp->tv_usec = 0; 
  return 0;
}
```

TLS libraries require the current time for certificate checks: SSL certificates are only valid within a certain date range.